# Installing package caret on a remote server running R version 3.2.1

Tags: linux, r, r-caret

I'm running R on a remote server (Linux machine), and I want to install packages caret and clusterSim. When I try to install I get the following prompt:

install.packages("caret")
Installing package into ‘/home/Gordonjo/R/s390x-ibm-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning message:
package ‘caret’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

And the same thing for clusterSim. Are these packages really not available for 3.2.1, or is there something I can do to get around this?

Comment: They install fine for me. The repo you're using may be outdated. Try switching repos.

Comment: I added the Rforge repository, and it started to install. Then it gave me a message that dependencies 'ggplot2', 'car', 'reshape2', 'plyr', 'BradleyTerry2' are not available. It removed the package and aborted the installation saying: 'installation of package caret had non-zero exit status'

Comment: Use `dependencies=TRUE` inside `install.packages`.

Comment: That helped. I also switched mirrors which seemed to help. Now I'm getting the following warning (for caret): "installation of BradleyTerry2 had a non-zero exit status, installation of package caret had a non zero exit status". For clusterSim I'm getting the same thing with package 'rgl'. Any idea why this is happening?